# Autogenerate credentials for Tuleap application login were not created in /root/.tuleap_passwd

Tags: tuleap

I have installed Tuleap 7.4 (as per Full installation from user guide), But the Application login credentials were not created in in /root/.tuleap_passwd

Below is the values in /roor/.tuleap_passwd

```
[root@HCL-PC /]# vi /root/.tuleap_passwd

Mysql user (root) : <redacted> 
Codendiadm unix & DB (codendiadm): <redacted>
Mailman siteadmin: <redacted>
Openfire DB user (openfireadm): <redacted>
Libnss-mysql DB user (dbauthuser): <redacted>
```

So from the above I could not see any credential (username / password) Tuleap Application login

Answer (score 1):

By default, after the installation process, the credentials are admin/siteadmin.

I strongly advise you to change these as soon as possible.

Regards,

Comment: thanks Martin, I tried with admin/siteadmin - not able to login, redirecting to same login screen, https://10.117.223.219/account/login.php?return_to=%2Fmy%2Findex.php%3Freturn_to%3D%252Fmy%252Findex.php